# Does GO iterate map entries always in the same order when using range?

Tags: dictionary, go, range

Will this code always display the same result?
Underlying question: will `range` always iterate a map in the same order?

```
m := map[string]int {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3,
    "d": 4,
    "e": 5,
    "f": 6,
}
for k, v := range m {
    fmt.Printf("%v = %v", k, v)
}
```

Comment: An easy way to get a consistent ordering is to use [the sort package](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/).

Comment: Interesting Question, I was going to say, "you should not rely on it in any language", but that would be incorrect apparently you can rely on it in Python: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20504062/1078084

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it is intentionally randomized (to keep programmers from relying on it, since it is not specified in the language spec).

from [the Go Blog](https://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action)

> Iteration order
>
> When iterating over a map with a range loop, the iteration order is not specified and is not guaranteed to be the same from one iteration to the next. Since the release of Go 1.0, the runtime has randomized map iteration order. Programmers had begun to rely on the stable iteration order of early versions of Go, which varied between implementations, leading to portability bugs.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I also came accross [this](https://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2014/04/27/a-surprising-feature-of-golang-that-colored-me-impressed/), which stole most of its content from the article you did link.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is: **No, it does not**.

I wrote the following test to assert that.

```
func Test_GO_Map_Range(t *testing.T) {
    originalMap := map[string]int {
        "a": 1,
        "b": 2,
        "c": 3,
        "d": 4,
        "e": 5,
        "f": 6,
    }
    getKeys := func(m map[string]int) []string{
        mapKeys := make([]string, len(m))
        i := 0
        for n := range m {
            mapKeys[i] = n
            i++
        }
        return mapKeys
    }
    keys := getKeys(originalMap)
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        assert.Equal(t, keys, getKeys(originalMap))
    }
}
```

I get results like:

```
Error:          Not equal: 
                expected: []string{"d", "e", "f", "a", "b", "c"}
                actual  : []string{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"}

Error:          Not equal: 
                expected: []string{"d", "e", "f", "a", "b", "c"}
                actual  : []string{"f", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e"}

Error:          Not equal: 
                expected: []string{"d", "e", "f", "a", "b", "c"}
                actual  : []string{"c", "d", "e", "f", "a", "b"}

Error:          Not equal: 
                expected: []string{"d", "e", "f", "a", "b", "c"}
                actual  : []string{"b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "a"}

Error:          Not equal: 
                expected: []string{"d", "e", "f", "a", "b", "c"}
                actual  : []string{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"}
```